# Keyboard doesn't work when booting from USB drive

Tags: arch-linux, boot, keyboard, grub, live-usb

I recently installed/tried a lot of linux operating systems, now I have fallen in love with ArchLinux which is by far the most promising(even if I will need about 3 months to configure it properly). I am booting Arch from a flash drive everything works fine I am getting a GRUB screen without any errors, the problem is that all my previous distros had a timeout which selected the default option(usually "Boot Live OS") so I didn't need to use my keyboard, but Arch doesn't have a timeout so I am blocked at the GRUB(or whatever it is called). Any ideas, by the way I have already tried to change the BIOS options and change ports. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your GRUB doesn't have a timeout. The simplest solution is to set it up and hope that later on the system will recognize your keyboard. You can do one of the following things:

1. mount the partition containing Live OS; you can achieve it but pluging the flash drive to the machine running another linux (like Debian or Ubuntu) or by booting other linux from another flash drive;  after you successfully mount the partition containing the Live OS, modify grub settings manually;
2. it may be possible to customize Live USB' GRUB with graphical interface like grub-customizer (after chrooting into it) but this option seems less probable than the first one.

ad. 1. [GRUB page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB) at Arch's wiki is insanely good (seriously). You can set up timeout manually by editing `/etc/default/grub` and then generating new `grub.cfg` with: `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Refer to [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Generate_the_main_configuration_file) section of the Mighty Arch Wiki ;) (chrooting into drive may be necessary).

Are you using USB or PS2 keyboard? It you are running Arch on PC you could give a good old PS a try. I had once a keyboard problem with GRUB installed on Arch (using USB Windows Natural 4000 keyboard on the first connection). But after the restart it all went on smoothly and grub reacted to the key strokes.

I am not an expert on Live OS versions, but it generally should work similar to the standalone installation (witch those I have some experience).

By the way, Arch is an excellent choice and I fully respect your enthusiasm about configuring it for 3 months. Although, for some aspects it can take you even more time to establish the proper functionality. Have fun doing it :)

Comment: Hahaha... Thanks buddy I will try your idea, btw I am using an USB keyboard(Serious Kompact 3000).